# Método de Gauss para resolver una matriz

Tags: c++, matrices

En este programa se intenta realizar el procedimiento del metodo de Gauss para resolver una matriz. La problematica se da cuando empiezan las iteraciones para convertir en cero los valores de la parte inferior de la matriz el programa calcula un valor, pero al momento de imprimirlo imprime uno totalmente diferente. Dicho valor erroneo es el que se toma para la siguiente iteración como valor verdadero, es decir, que esto termina afectando el resultado final de la matriz.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int u=0,N,i,j;
float aux,aux1,V[30][30]={0},C[30];
cout<<"DIMENSION:   ";
cin>>N;

system("cls");

for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    cout<<"INGRESE VALORES MATRIZ:"<<endl;
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        cout<<i+1<<j+1<<":  ";
        cin>>V[i][j];
    }
    cout<<"INGRESE CONSTANTE: ";
    cin>>C[i];
    system("cls");
}
system("cls");

for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        cout<<V[i][j]<<"\t";            
    }
    cout<<"|\t"<<C[i];
    cout<<endl;
}

system("pause");
do{
    system("cls");
//      for(i=0;i<N;i++){
//          for(j=0;j<N;j++){
//              if(i==j&&V[i][j]==0){
//                  cout<<"LA MATRIZ NO TIENE SOLUCION";
//                  return 0;
//              }
//          }
//      }   

    aux1=0;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            if(i==u){
                aux=V[u][u];
                V[i][j]=(V[i][j]/aux);
                C[i]=(C[i]/aux);
            }
        }
    }


    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            cout<<V[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<"|\t"<<C[i];
        cout<<endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Aplicando el Metodo Gauss para Resolucion de Ecuaciones Lineales hemos observado
//  que los valores que corresponden a las coordenadas, al momento de imprimir
//  no coinciden. Ej: en V[2][2] el valor registrado que debe guardar es -2
//  pero al momento de imprimir mu
    cout<<"ENTRANDO"<<endl;
    for(i=u+1;i<N;i++){
        float aux3;
        aux3=V[i][u];
        for(j=u;j<N;j++){
                cout<<i<<endl;
                cout<<j<<endl;
                cout<<"b: "<<V[i][j]<<endl;
                V[i][j]=((-aux3*V[u][j])+V[i][j]);
                cout<<"a: "<<V[i][j]<<endl;
                cout<<"aux: "<<aux3<<endl;
                system("pause");
        }
            C[i]=((-aux3*C[u])+C[i]);
            cout<<C[i]<<endl;
            system("pause");
    }
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            cout<<V[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<"|\t"<<C[i];
        cout<<endl;
    }
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            if(i==j){
                aux1=aux1+V[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    u++;
}while(aux1!=N);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No tengo ni idea de cómo [resolver sistemas de ecuaciones por el método de Gauss [image]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Example_of_the_algorithm) (he intentado documentarme para responder a tu pregunta pero no me aclaro). De lo que sí tengo idea es de C++ y te diré que si tienes errores en tu código es porque programas de una manera que es propensa a generar errores:

- **No sigues el [principio de responsabilidad única](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica)**: Cada función debería hacer una sola tarea, esto ayuda a [modularizar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularidad_(inform%C3%A1tica)) el código y un código modular es más fácil de entender y depurar.
- **Tus variables no tienen nombres auto-explicativos**: Los nombres de una sola letra como `u`, `N`, `i`, `j`, `V` y `C` no explican nada del objetivo ni función de las variables, los nombres como `aux` y `aux1` son tan genéricos que tampoco aportan información alguna. El nombre de una variable debería permitir saber de un vistazo su cometido, haciendo que el código sea menos propenso a errores y haciendo que sea más fácil de leer y entender, cosa que cualquier persona que trabaje contigo (incluso tu yo futuro) agradecerá mucho.
- **Deja que tu código respire**: en los 90 teníamos pantallas de 80 caracteres de ancho y 25 líneas de alto (no había más remedio que compactar el código), pero hace décadas que no tenemos esas limitaciones, pon unos espacios en el código: hará que sea más fácil de leer y tu yo del futuro te lo agradecerá.

Siguiendo las premisas anteriores, te aconsejo crear unos alias de tipos para tu matriz y tu constante:

```
using Matriz = float[30][30];
using Constante = float[30];
```

Con estos alias, podrías definir unas funciones para recopilar o mostrar datos:

```
void rellenar_datos(int dimension, Matriz &matriz, Constante &constante)
{
    using namespace std;

    for (int fila = 0; fila < dimension; ++fila)
    {
        cout << "INGRESE VALORES MATRIZ:\n";

        for(int columna = 0; columna < dimension; ++columna)
        {
            cout << fila + 1 << columna + 1 << ":  ";
            cin >> matriz[fila][columna];
        }

        cout << "INGRESE CONSTANTE: ";

        cin >> constante[fila];
    }
}

void mostrar_datos(int dimension, Matriz &matriz, Constante &constante)
{
    using namespace std;

    for (int fila = 0; fila < dimension; ++fila)
    {
        for (int columna = 0; columna < dimension ;++columna)
        {
            cout << matriz[fila][columna] << '\t';            
        }
        cout << "|\t" << constante[fila] << '\n';
    }    
}
```

Que siendo usadas, hacen que tu código sea más legible y comprensible:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int dimension;
    Matriz matriz;
    Constante constante;

    cout << "DIMENSION:   ";
    cin >> dimension;

    rellenar_datos(dimension, matriz, constante);
    mostar_datos(dimension, matriz, constante);

    // ....
    return 0;
}
```

El resto de tu código para mi es un galimatías incomprensible, pero creo que podría quedar así:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int dimension;
    Matriz matriz;
    Constante constante;

    cout << "DIMENSION:   ";
    cin >> dimension;

    rellenar_datos(dimension, matriz, constante);
    mostar_datos(dimension, matriz, constante);

    do {
        normalizar(dimension, matriz, constante);
        mostar_datos(dimension, matriz, constante);
        operar(dimension, matriz, constante);
    } while (/**/);

    return 0;
}
```

Te agradecería que siguieses estos consejos y compartas tus avances.